# WCF serviceactivation enumeration

Tags: .net, wcf

I need to add a "serviceactivation" element to my web.config file. However, I can't find anywhere on the web what the 4 enumerations mean and which one to use for the "**add service**=".

Here is the code in the web.config with each of the enumerations. How do I determine which one to use?

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add service="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" relativeAddress="http://yeagertech.com/yeagerte/YeagerTechWcfService.YeagerTechWcfService.svc"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

NLog.LogReceiverService.LogReceiverForwardingService
System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService
System.Web.ApplicationServices.ProfileService
System.Web.ApplicationServices.RoleService
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set this to the class that implements your service.  I show an example of how to use this setting here.

http://rickrainey.com/2013/08/30/hosting-a-wcf-service-in-an-azure-web-role-with-http-tcp-endpoints/